# Integrate Bootstrap into existing community site's page css not fully working

Tags: force.com-sites, bootstrap

I am trying to integrate bootstrap into an existing community site's page that was delivered by a vendor to our organization and some of the styling/layout on the page we would like to now change. In order to make the changes my organization wants, I was hoping to implement Twitter Bootstrap without too much of a re-write on the Visualforce just for time sake. However it seems that my Bootstrap implementation is only partially getting implemented. Can anyone see anything wrong with my implementation of Twitter Bootstrap or does the conflict lie elsewhere per the provided Visualforce source code below:

```
    <apex:page Controller="ClassNoteController" sidebar="false" showHeader="true" standardStylesheets="false">
    <!-- BEGIN STYLES -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.css"></link>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap336, 'bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap336, 'bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css.map')}"/>
    <!--  END  STYLES -->

    <!-- BEGIN SCRIPTS -->
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.Jquery1120}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Bootstrap336, 'bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')}"/>
    <!--  END  SCRIPTS -->

    <script>
        var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
        j$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#projectTable').DataTable({
                "searching" : false,
                "lengthChange" : false,
                "pageLength" : 25,
                "info" : true,
                "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
                "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) 
                {
                    makeImgClickable();
                    /* $('.bodyDiv').height($('#projectTable_wrapper').height()+300); */
                }
            });

            $('.table-project img').css('height', '');
            $('.table-project img').css('width', '');

            makeImgClickable();
        });

        function makeImgClickable()
        { 
            $('.sfdc_richtext img').each(function ()
            {
                var currentImage = $(this); 
                currentImage.wrap("<a target='_blank' href='" + currentImage.attr("src") + "' />");
            });

            /*$('.paginate_button').each(function() {
                $(this).click(function(){ 
                    makeImgClickable();
                });
            });*/
        }
    </script>

    <style>
/*CSS to hide thedatelinkwhichappearalongDatepickerwhileusinginputfield*/
.dateInput .dateFormat {
    display: none !important;
}

.hide {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#displayHeader th {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#totalDisplay {
    background-color: #f2f3f3;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    margin-right: 47px;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.tablesorter-blue th,.tablesorter-blue td {
    border: none;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #d9d9d9;
}

#displayRecordsTable td {
    padding-top: 0.5%;
}

.table-project img {
  width: 100px !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
</style>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageMessages />
        <apex:outputfield value="{!communityWebContent.Page_Content__c}" />
        <apex:CommandButton styleClass="btn-primary" value="Submit a Class Note" action="{!redirectToSubmitPage}" />
        <div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-header"><h4 class="panel-title">Details:</h4></div>
                <table id="projectTable" class="table-project table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>

                            <apex:repeat value="{!lstCustomSettingFields}" var="objField">
                                <th><apex:outputText value="{!objField['Label__c']}" /></th>
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <apex:repeat value="{!lstClassNotes}" var="classNoteObj">
                        <tr>
                            <apex:repeat value="{!lstCustomSettingFields}" var="objField">
                                <td>
                                    <apex:outputField value="{!classNoteObj[objField['Field_Name__c']]}"/>
                                </td>
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </table>
            </div>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Any suggestions/tips would be greatly appreciated, I am still getting used to Visualforce/Apex Coding after coming from a .NET background.

[image: Compares Bootstrap styling I am expecting with what I am actually seeing on the page]

Comment: Can you provide some more information such as an error being received, or unexpected behavior? It will help us zero in on the issue.

Comment: Just a suggestion, move your script and includeScript statements at the bottom of the page. Regarding your issue, is it the data table which is causing the issue?

Comment: Definitely move your scripts to the bottom of the page as suggested above. Also post up some screenshots of what you are seeing with maybe what you are expecting? If you want to really cheat this project and only have requirements for basic bootstrap elements, check out Visualstrap as its a great starting point for bootstrap styling of common visualforce elements. That ShowHeader true is going to import some Salesforce styles that may be competing with the bootstrap stuff but no way to tell unless we see some stuff.

Comment: Thank you both I am moving the script tags like you suggested... I was trying to avoid having to go through someone else's code as this was supposed to be delivered for us, but unfortunately it was delivered as a solution prior to us settling on a styling. Please see my picture it should show the unexpected behavior. But basically the issues are: the apex: CommandButton isn't getting the btn-primary class correctly something is preventing the style from taking place and the panel panel-primary is missing the top header section (blue collar) it is just putting the border around the table.